# React POST request is sent without cookie

Tags: reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I'm struggling with an Axios POST request that does want to send cookie in its headers.

My API route `/search/producers` is working with Postman : once logged in, this route answers with correct data.

With Axios POST request, the server can not find `req.user` because the cookie is not sent.

In my browser, I always get a `401 OPTIONS` response.

Response headers :

```
OPTIONS /search/producers HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4242
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type,withcredentials
Referer: http://localhost:3000/home
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Connection: keep-alive
```

Request headers :

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 28
ETag: W/"1c-IxTdph/1tV0PHzy4xuP38jYWJTg"
Date: Thu, 25 Jun 2020 22:26:37 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
```

Here is my code server-side :

The function that checks `req.user` (created with [Passport](http://www.passportjs.org/))

```
function isAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.headers.cookie) // always undefined with Axios request
    if (req.user){
        return next();
    }else{
        return res.status(401).json('Denied access')
    }
}
```

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS");
    next();
});
```

```
app.use('/search', isAuthenticated, searchRoutes); // OK with Postman POST, blocks with Axios POST
```

The route itself :

```
router.post('/producers', function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.product) {
        Producers.find({productsCategories: {$regex: req.body.product, $options: 'i'}})
          .then(result => {
              return res.json(result)
          })
          .catch(error => {
              return res.json("Internal Server Error")
          })
    }
})
```

I set up `withCredentials: true` client-side :

```
const instance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
})
```

```
instance
  .post("search/producers", { product })
    .then(res => {
      ...
    })
```

All "GET" requests work perfectly, sending the Cookie in request header.

Can you help me to figure out what's wrong or missing in my code please ? Thanks for any idea.

[**EDIT**] I decided to use npm package `cors` and it worked :

For those interested :

```
const cors = require('cors');
```

```
const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS'],
    credentials: true
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: what happens if you send the withCredentials prop in each call instead of using the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's related to this issue:
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/876

replace your API call with the following

```
axios({
  url: API_BASE + "search/producers",
  withCredentials: true
  method: "POST",
  data: qs.stringify(product), 
}).then(response => {
...
});
```